# Fastest way to save/load data.table

Tags: r, data.table

What I would like to do is actually use the fastest available method to store `data.table`s for further processing.

Something along the lines of:

1. Read original data from CSV/RDS.
2. Convert it to a `data.table`.
3. Save it into a format optimized for re-reading (RDS doesn't seem to work with `data.table`, is that right? Is there some other binary option?)
4. Continue to work over with file from step #3, reading it directly as a `data.table` over and over again, doing slicing, grouping, plotting, ...

What is the best option for step #3?

Comment: You don't like `save()`?

Comment: I use `save()` with `compress = FALSE`. It is quite fast.

Comment: @Arthur Well, not that I don't like save, but `All R platforms use the XDR (bigendian) representation of C ints and doubles in binary save-d files, and these are portable across all R platforms`. Thus, it clearly involves in/out conversion on most common x64 platform I'm using. So wondering is there anything better around here, maybe someone already checked all options and did some measurements.

Comment: I've run benchmark a while ago, it turns out that sqlite was fastest interface. I've compared rds, db and csv. Don't have the link but it can be found in data.table issues on github.

Comment: The link Jan mentioned: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/943

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here some measurements on particular dataset I'm using. It is originally in RDS, and reading it takes 60+ seconds.

After that DT was saved as internal XDR as well as SQLite db, both uncompressed.

1. save()/load() pair was fastest, 11.7-11.8 seconds load
2. SQLite (dbReadTable) was pretty close, 12.0-12.1 seconds. File size with DB is about 30% smaller, so I could imagine the case where SQLite would be faster than save()/load().

For now save()/load() is for me, and it preserves class as well